# Text analysis software similar to Concordance

Tags: windows, text-processing

[Concordance](http://www.concordancesoftware.co.uk/) is "software for concordancing and text analysis", and was famously used to identify patterns in the writing of Agatha Christie. It is "not at present available for download or purchase because of compatibility issues after recent updates to Windows". Does anyone know of similar software?

Comment: Maybe you could run an old version of Windows in a VM? Perhaps they would sell to you then.

Comment: @EricShain I doubt it; I was quoting their website. I don't think they thought it through.

Comment: Could be worth asking.